# If $A_c$ is either the empty set of a finite set. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded real-valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$

$$A_c = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = c\}$$

is either the empty set of a finite set. Show that f is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Edited: This is my solution.
$A_c$ is closed because it is the inverse image of $\{c\}$ (so $f$ is continuous), since it finite or empty, so it is compact. Thus $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: First show that the limits of $f$ at $\pm\infty$ exist (look at limsups and liminfs).